# How to solve this git rename/delete merge conflict?

Tags: git

I have two branches, `master` and `develop`. At the state of commit `A`, a `fileA` is in the directory `/folderX/subfolderY/fileA` (and tracked). Now commit `B` on master moves `fileA` to the parent directory `/folderX/fileA` (without modifying it); then comes commit `C` which does some more stuff on other files. Commit `D` in `develop` **modifies** `fileA` and moves it to the parent folder as well. The content of commit `D` is therefore

1. delete `/folderX/subfolderY/fileA`
2. create `/folderX/fileA`.

Note that `fileA` is tracked in both branches.

```
--A--B--C   master
   \
    D       develop
```

I would like to keep the modified version of `fileA` of develop in the end.

Now if I merge `develop` into `master`, git tells me there is a merge conflict because `fileA` has been created in master but deleted in `develop`. More precisely, it states:

`CONFLICT (rename/delete): /folderX/subfolderY/fileA deleted in D develop and renamed to /folderX/fileA in HEAD. Version HEAD of /folderX/fileA left in tree.`

If I try to resolve with `git mergetool`, git gives me the usual options:

```
Deleted merge conflict for '/folderX/fileA':
  {local}: created file
  {remote}: deleted
Use (c)reated or (d)eleted file, or (a)bort?
```

However, if I choose `(c)created`, the unmodified version of `fileA` is retained. If I choose `(d)eleted`, I end up without `fileA`.

I expected git to compare `/folderX/fileA` from master to the modified `/folderX/fileA` from develop and to create a merge commit out of the resulting difference. What am I missing

Answer (score 2):

You can do git merge by ignoring rename.

```
git merge -s recursive -Xno-renames develop
```

This will result in git reporting the file modified by both the branches. Now you can use `git mergetool` or run, `git checkout --theirs folderX/fileA` to get develop version.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the file as it is in D, because B only renamed it (to the same thing as D):

```
git checkout D -- folderX/fileA
```

And remove other conflicting instances of the file that are in the index.

Comment: That does not solve the merge correctly but replaces the file manually afterward.

Comment: @00schneider how so?

Comment: When do I have to do this? During the merge, do I remove the "created" file of B from the index and grab the file from D and commit?

Comment: When you merge and get the conflicts, you run that to take care of the conflict on _that_ file. If you see that the file is also showing up as conflicted with the original name, `git rm` it.

Comment: But do I see a diff between the old folderX/fileA and the new folderX/fileA then? Or is it seen as a new file?

Comment: ??? Following your instructions, **both branches** end up with the file in the exact same spot... **and** only D changed its content. Therefore, regardless of which branch you are merging on which (dev onto master or viceversa), normal merge flow would ask for the file to be just like it is in D (and with the same name as it is in D). If you merge D onto C, you will get a difference, if you merge C onto D, the file ends up being as it is in HEAD.... and in both cases you will run the exact same command I said on my answer.